# Where can I get a logback dtd?

Tags: logback, dtd

When I use logback.xml to config, it always cann't provide tips, so I wanne get a DTD schema for logback, where can I get it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#syntax) (emphasis added by me):

> As will be demonstrated over and over, the syntax of logback configuration files is extremely flexible. **As such, it is not possible to specify the allowed syntax with a DTD file or an XML schema.** Nevertheless, the very basic structure of the configuration file can be described as, `<configuration>` element, containing zero or more `<appender>` elements, followed by zero or more `<logger>` elements, followed by at most one `<root>` element. The following diagram illustrates this basic structure.
>
> [image: basic configuration file structure]